# Jquery detect hover over an element but not the elements contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Here is the page i am working with: http://jimeagle.com/new/music/

I want to make it so when you hover over a row the image shows and when you leave the row the image shows, but because (i think) the image is in the hover div, the image stays visible when you hover out of the row but over the image.

I tried to move the image out of the hover div but it caused some horrible flickering because when your over the image you are no longer over the hover div.

Any way around this? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. Could you please rephrase the description of your problem?

Comment: If you hover over a number, the image shows, then move your mouse down to the next number and the image doesn't go away. What I'd like is the image to hide and the next rows image to show.

Comment: its working like you have said

Comment: If your over the number 01 and you move your mouse directly to number 02 - (for me at least), the image for number 01 stays there the whole time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the height of the `div` with the `class "music_row"`. If the mouse y-position (on `mousemove`) is higher then the calculated height, hide the `image`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iHeight = $(".music_row").height();  
    $(".music_wrapper")
        .mouseover(function() {
            $(this).find('.image').show();
        })
        .mousemove(function(o) {
            if (o.layerY > iHeight) {
                $(this).find('.image').hide();
            }
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            $(this).find('.image').hide();         
        });
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KAuRF/).

Comment: Works great, I had just started to try a similar method but would have taken me hours! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Because the image is a child of the element you bind the handlers on, it will prevent the mouseout event being triggered unless the pointer also leaves the container, `.music_wrapper` in your case.

To work around this, you could create an absolute positioned 'ghost' element with zero opacity and use this for triggering your hover events. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.music_wrapper').each(function() {
        var ghost = $(this).find('.music_row').clone();
        ghost.css({opacity: 0, position: 'absolute', overflow: 'hidden' });
        ghost.hover(
            function() { $(this).parent().find('img').show(); },
            function() { $(this).parent().find('img').hide(); }
        );
        $(this).append(ghost);
    });
})
```

Not tested, but this should recreate your `.music_row` div element in every `.music_wrapper`, set some css properties, bind the hover handlers and append it to the wrapper element.

Now image and hover element are seperated, which can hide the image even when the mouse is still over it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not doing this, actually. I think the intuitive thing is that when you hover over the number / text the image pops up, but moving your mouse inside the image shouldn't do anything.

How about just moving the images to the right a little so that the big numbers are still at least partly visible? Then it would feel natural to move over to the next # to see the next image.